# 99 notifications?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

Suddenly I'm getting '99 notifications', though only 4 are shown, 3 of these stale.

[image: Screenshot as of 11:40 EST]

This was only seen  on programmers.SO; other sites show no new notifications, as they should.

This was a freshly opened tab, not an auto-updated previously open one.

Comment: [status-completed], the bug was caught earlier today and fixed (afaik). In the first version of the bug you'd see the 222/99 notifications (not just the counter), so this might just be a UI bug or stale cache.

Comment: It's not a bug, the counter is just separate from the actual notifications. The counter just has to be manually cleared by every user

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135579/the-heinz-notification-bug-strikes-again and the question it's closed as a dupe of.

Comment: Why was this closed as 'Too localized'? I encountered the very same issue!

Comment: @JimG. It's traditional for bugs that were fixed, the "specific moment in time" reason applies, i.e. this is now fixed, won't affect anyone else anymore. Think about it in terms of whether the question will benefit from any answers past the point of the bug getting fixed...